# Fill DataGrid with stored procedure (Silverlight business application)

Tags: silverlight, stored-procedures, silverlight-4.0

I need fill datagrid with a stored procedure. With asp.net I did it

http://g1204.hizliresim.com/w/5/43qb1.jpg

but with Silverlight I can't do that.

http://e1203.hizliresim.com/v/x/3x3dw.jpg

Here is the code how can I fill datagrid with asp.net:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

// Open the connection 
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
   cnn.Open(); 

   cmd.Connection = cnn;
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   cmd.CommandText = "sp_get_Scorelist";

   cmd.Parameters.Add("d1", new DateTime(2012, 03, 01));
   cmd.Parameters.Add("d2", DateTime.Now);

   using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
   {
       da.Fill(dt);
   }
}          

GridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Here is my stored procedure;

```
USE [ATLAS] 
GO 
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_get_Scorelist]    Script Date: 05.04.2012 14:54:30 ******/ 
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO 
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO 
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[sp_get_Scorelist](@d1 datetime,@d2 datetime) 
AS 
BEGIN 
SET FMTONLY OFF --SQL 2008 sonrası desteği yok, bir sonraki sürümde problem çıkacak 
SET NOCOUNT ON 
DECLARE @DT1 DateTime ,@DT2 DateTime ,@ToDay DateTime 
DECLARE @Name nvarchar(25), @Surname nvarchar(25) , @EID int, @DayScore nvarchar(25) 
DECLARE @Query varchar(Max), @FName varchar(80) 
if (select name from tempdb..sysobjects where name like '#ScoreList%') <> '' DROP TABLE #Scorelist 
Create Table  #ScoreList (Name nvarchar(25),Surname nvarchar(25),ID int) 
SET @DT1=@D1 
SET @DT2=@D2 
WHILE @DT1 <= @DT2   
BEGIN 
  SET @FName = Convert (Varchar(2),DATEPART(day,@DT1))+'_'+Convert(Varchar(2),DATEPART(month,@DT1)) -- +Convert(Varchar(4),DATEPART(Year,@DT1)) 
  SET @Query=N'ALTER TABLE #ScoreList ADD F'+ @FName +' nvarchar(25)' 
  EXECUTE(@Query) 
  DECLARE CRS_ALLOTMENT CURSOR FOR   
  --SET DATEFIRST 1 
    Select hr.Name, hr.Surname, hr.EmployeeID, sc.DayScore from hr_scoring sc left join hr_employee hr on  sc.EmployeeID = hr.employeeID Where ScoreDate=@Dt1 
OPEN CRS_ALLOTMENT   
FETCH NEXT FROM CRS_ALLOTMENT INTO @Name ,@Surname ,@EID ,@DayScore  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS =0 
BEGIN         
  IF (Select Count(*) FROM #ScoreList Where ID=@EID ) > 0 
  BEGIN 
    SET @Query=N'UPDATE #ScoreList Set F'+@FName+'='''+@DayScore+''' Where ID='+ Convert(varchar(30),@EID) 
  END 
  ELSE 
  BEGIN 
SET @Query=N'INSERT INTO #ScoreList (Name,Surname,ID,F'+@FName+') Values('''+@Name+''' '+','+' '''+ @SurName+ ' '''+ ','+Convert(Varchar(25),@EID)+','+' '''+@DayScore+' '''+') ' 
  END 
      EXECUTE(@Query)          
FETCH NEXT FROM CRS_ALLOTMENT INTO @Name ,@Surname ,@EID ,@DayScore  
END 
  CLOSE CRS_ALLOTMENT 
  DEALLOCATE CRS_ALLOTMENT     
    SET @DT1 = @DT1+1 
END 


Select * From #Scorelist Order By Name,SurName 

END
```

My question is how can I fill datagrid from the stored procedure in Silverlight?

It should in domain service or in server side? If you write an example will be great.

Thanks anyway

Comment: Take a look at this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx)

Comment: Much better, but you should have edited your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956931/fill-silverlight-datagrid-with-stored-procedure-entity-framework)

Answer (score 0):

Just think about where and how your code is running for a minute:

- in **ASP.NET**, everything is run on the **(web) server** and turned into HTML which is sent down to the client to be displayed in the browser. Your code entirely **runs on the server** (except for Javascript scripts) - therefore it *can* directly access the database server and the stored procedure
- in **Silverlight** on the other hand, **your code runs on the client** inside the Silverlight plugin. There's no database server there - most likely, that client machine also cannot connect directly to the database server from his location.

So in Silverlight, you need to make all data access through the domain service. Your domain service needs to expose a method to fetch that data and return it in some way that the SL client can display it on the client's machine